# In Unity2d, Does not `transform.right = Vector2.left` means 180 degree clockwise rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, transform

I'm using the `transform.right` property to rotate my `GameObject`, because modifying a Basis vector is as rotating a object (suppose `basisX = (0,-1), basisY = (1,0), v = (1,2)`, then the linear combination results in `(0,-1) * 1 + 2 * (1,0) = (2,-1)`, so the vector `v` dids 90 degree clockwise rotation).

```
class SpinningTop : MonoBehaviour {
  public float rad = 0f;
  public Text  text; // initialized in the inspector

  private void FixedUpdate() {
    transform.right = new Vector2(
      Mathf.Cos(rad), -Mathf.Sin(rad) // rotate basisX
    );
    rad += Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    text.text = $"up: {transform.up}\n right: {transform.right}";
  }
}
```

using the fact, the above script component `SpinningTop` rotates the `gameObject` by 1 degree for every call to `FixedUpdate`. for example, when `transform.right = Vector3.down`, `transform.up = Vector3.right`. But, there is one problem:
[image]

Exactly only when `transform.right = Vector3.left (-1,0,0)`, the rotation becomes weird:

[image]

when `transform.right = Vector3.left`, `transform.up` is set to `Vector3.up`. Is `transform.right` (the result I expected was `transform.up = Vector3.down`).Is `transform.right` an attribute that should not be used for rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get what you've actually tried to achieve. `transform.right` is a world vector of transform's red arrow direction, so however the transform is rotated, its red arrow is pointing to its relative right. In opposite, `Vector3.right` is a global red axis (x) in positive direction, with no rotations applied. Effectively `transform.right` would be equal `transform.rotation * Vector3.right`.

And you doesn't need to manually do fancy math to rotate objects, just do one of this:

- `transform.Rotate(axis, angle);`
- `transform.RotateAround(point, angle, axis);`
- `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z);`
- `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, upward);`

...etc, there is a tons of way to rotate things. But please, please don't modify `transform.-side` vectors directly, although it is possible, it is not reliable way to do things unless in some special corner cases.

Comment: Thank you. When I used ``transform.right``, It worked fine except for the question. so, I thought it was transforming the basis of the local coordinate system. I wanted to make rotation using a direction vector. so, I did this with ``transform.right``. I think it's better to use a different method. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why should the up vector change just because you rotate the object around Y?

[source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/906c6894a0014ada369cefde96b51e30acc4246e/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs#L48)

> ```
>  public Vector3 right { get { return rotation * Vector3.right; } set { rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right, value); } }
> ```

-> it uses [`Quaternion.FromToRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) which doesn't care for any incremental rotation logic - it uses the delta between `Vector3.right` and `Vector3.left` which is a 180° rotation, either around `Y` or around `Z`

=> `Quaternion` prioritizes the Y axis as the global up so it tries to maintain it that way and rather rotates that one.

=> `transform.up` still points up.

As already mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76712233/7111561) there are a couple ways for how to rotate you object.

In your case you most probably rather want to simply go with

```
private void FixedUpdate() 
{
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 1f * Time.deltaTime); // 1 degree per second

    text.text = $"up: {transform.up:G9}\n right: {transform.right:G9}";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the reason why I focused on the up vector changing was that when only ``transform.right = Vector3.left`` was used, the result is different from others. I wanted to make rotation using a direction vector. so, I did this with ``transform.right``.  But after looking at the source code you showed me, I think it's better to use a different method. Thank you!